# FTP size command run in linux shell but doesn't work in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ftp

I'm making a linux script to get the size of a file present on a ftp server.
I'm using this command sequence

```
ftp -n X.X.X.X
user username password
cd dir_name
size file_name
quit
```

When I run this command one by one in the linux shell it returns the size dimension as I want.
When I write this command in a script in this way

```
remote_size=`ftp -n X.X.X.X<<EOF
user username $password
cd dir_name
size file_name
quit
EOF`
echo $remote_size
```

the remote_size variable is void.
Can you explain me this behaviour and suggest me a solution to get the size?
Thanks

**UPDATE**: When I pass to size command a not exists file the remote_size variable contains the error message `The system cannot find the file specified.` returned by the ftp server. Only when I pass an existent file the ftp server returns nothing so the remote_size variable is void

**UPDATE 2:** This is the output if i pass an existent file or a not existent file

```
remote_size=`ftp -n X.X.X.X<<EOF
user username $password
cd dir_name
size file_name (existent file)
quit
EOF`
echo "REMOTE_SIZE="$remote_size
```

Output: `REMOTE_SIZE=`

```
remote_size=`ftp -n X.X.X.X<<EOF
user username $password
cd dir_name
size file_name (not existent file)
quit
EOF`
echo "REMOTE_SIZE="$remote_size
```

Output: `REMOTE_SIZE=The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: Could it be that your `ftp` outputs the size to stderr instead of stdout?

Comment: Yes maybe it can be the problem, now I tried to get the size for a not exists file and the remote_size variable contains the error message returned by the ftp server. But if this is the problem how can I tell to ftp command to read the stdout? With the other ftp commands as ls it works fine

Comment: I tried to redirect the message on the file test.log with &>test.log. When I pass to the command size a not exists file the file test.log contains the error message but when I pass to the command size the file that exists on ftp server the file test.log remain empty

Comment: Under what circumstances do you see the `size` command output the size information? Is it only when you run the command without any redirection (this implies also without catching the stdout)? Which `ftp` client are you using (`ftp --version`)?

Comment: I see the `size` output when I pass a not exists file to the command, if I redirect the output on a file I see the output on the file otherwise I see the output on the screen. When I pass an existent file to the `size` command I have no output nether on the screen or on the output file. I tried also with `ls` command, if I run the ftp script with only `ls` I receive the output, if I run `ls file_name` I have no output, seem as the ftp command in a bash file doesn't manage the parameter, because also the `ls file_name` on a shell work fine. The ftp version is `0.17-67.e17`

Comment: So the whole issue is about the use of the _size_ command in an FTP session. `size` returns the size of the file on the **remote** host. You claim that you do get an output, if the file does **not** exist. How can you get the size of a non-existing file? This does not make sense. Can you illustrate this with an example? Just run an interactive ftp session which exhibits this behaviour, and post a link to the screenshot. I can't believe this....

Comment: Sorry, I explain better. when I pass a not existing file in the script, the ftp return the message `The system cannot find the file specified.` in the variable remote_size. When I pass an existing file I think the remote_size variable has to contain the number of the size as you told but the script return nothing and the variable remote_size is empty. If I run the same commands one by one in the shell instead I can see the correct number of the size of the file, the problem is only in the bash script

Comment: Please post the output of the example `ftp` command.

Comment: `remote_size=\`ftp -n X.X.X.X<<EOF
user username $password
cd dir_name
size file_name (existent file)
quit
EOF\`
echo "REMOTE_SIZE="$remote_size`

Output: `REMOTE_SIZE=`

`remote_size=\`ftp -n X.X.X.X<<EOF
user username $password
cd dir_name
size file_name (not existent file)
quit
EOF\`
echo "REMOTE_SIZE="$remote_size`

Output: `REMOTE_SIZE=The system cannot find the file specified.`